My Lenovo T14s uses a 11.55v 3 cell battery, can I charge it with a Dell 3502 that uses an 11.4 3 cell battery?
I just need to get the computer on enough to turn off a setting and it will fix the issue I have with my USB ports. I have  T14 Gen 1 (type 20S0, 20S1) Laptop (ThinkPad) - Type 20S0 which uses    5B10W13905. I also have a Dell Inspiron 3502 which has a 3 cell 11.4v 48w. Can I open the Dell up and plug the T14s battery into it and charge it then remove it and put my Lenovo battery back into the Lenovo?
There is no way to charge this Lenovo, as my USB ports are all shut off.
https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-t-series-laptops/thinkpad-t14-type-20s0-20s1/20s0/parts/display/compatible

Are you asking if you can use the Dell battery to power the Lenovo or if you can charge the Lenovo with the Dell?

You know Ramhound I did not even consider that, I was one track minded on charging the Lenovo battery with the Dell's hardward and putting it back in.  Would either work?

OEM(s) intentionally design their products to support specific battery parts. It’s difficult to use the same product between product iterations from the same manufacturer. Lenovo and Dell are large enough where they would have their own manufacturing facilities for batteries (or be able to partner for their own manufacturing line from a partner). In other words I doubt it.

Specifically if the connection were identical, would it be safe to plug it in based on the voltage etc... I have another Lenovo, but its a 6cell 15v. I doubt the ports are identical for the Dell but before I open it up I thought it best to consult.

What do I need to charge this Lenovo battery?

Your asking me to confirm if something is safe without being able to place my hands on it, I won’t do that, I absolutely refuse to answer if it’s “safe”. Essentially since I more or less indicated that Dell and Lenovo intentionally design products to work with specific batteries. There isn’t a “battery” standard I can look at and say one way or another. The chances of the IC for the battery even being compatible is 0% than humanly conceivable

So with that idea out, what options can I do to get power to this computer without the usb charger ports working and the battery at critical?

I would take the device to a technician who could resolve the problem with the USB ports so the device can be charged.

Your laptop technically have 2 USB-C port... the primary one (with the charging logo) and the one with the side docking port (next to it) - Ref Document From Lenovo - You might be able to charge using the other port? The document (page 11-12) seems to indicate you can charge using both ports (#1 #2 #3).
